# RDLC report sorting header

Tags: report, rdlc

Is there a way to provide headers for the results of a sort in rdlc reports. e.g.
for

---

### *Names*         *Profession*

- Allan K, -   Programmer
- David M,  -  Networker
- Irene N,   - Programmer
- Moses X,   - Networker
- Gerad Z,   - Database

when i sort by Profession, i should get

Programmer

- Allan K   Prog
- Irene N   Prog

Networker

- David M   Netw
- Moses X   Netw

Database

- Gerad Z   Data

NOTE: that the sorted items are under headers (Programmer, Network and Database). How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer to my question. The data is in a table or matrix. What I did was put the matrix in a List and set the List to group by Profession and sort by Profession. Then I set the matrix rows to group by Names and sort by Profession. What happens is that the matrix repeats itsself for every Profession. As for the header, I set the top-left cell of the matrix to `=Fields!Profession.Value`

Answer (score 0):

You Can use UserSort property for header in properties window and under that you set SortExpression property to `=Fields!Profession.Value`

Comment: thanks alot. i have already done that and it does the job, but, it does not do one thing: separating the sorted data. e.g if you sort by profession, there should be a mini heading of the proffession name followed by rows of data of people under the proffessio and so on